# .bat file - TXT Log downloaded files, if its repeated, then delete

Tags: batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

New code still not working :( please help me fix this

```
@ECHO OFF 
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET "SEARCH_DIR=%~dp0FILES"

FOR /F "tokens=*" "%%a" IN (log.txt) DO (
    FOR /R "%SEARCH_DIR%" %%f IN (*%%a*) DO (
        if "%%f"="%%a" do del /Q "%%f"
else "%%f" >> log.txt

    )
)
pause
```

i need help with one line of a script to check for repeated files.
Right now i have:

```
set "path=C:\cygwin64\bin;%path%"
lynx -dump -nonumbers https://XXXXXXXXX.com/mypdf/ | grep https://XXXXXX.com/pdf >> links.txt
set "path=C:\cygwin64\bin;%path%"
wget -nd --content-disposition --trust-server-names -i links.txt -P .\PDF\
```

After downloading files from sites
1.pdf
2.pdf
3.pdf

**Script should be running like:
For downloaded files, If file aren't the same (by name.pdf) as saved in log.txt then add their names in log.txt, else delete file**
Please help me figure out how to write it. 
I think it should be partly

```
pushd "%~dp0PDF"
FOR /F eol^=^ delims^= %%F in ('2^>nul dir /b "*.pdf"^|findstr something something in log.txt ... do del /Q "%%F" 
if not >> log.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Some options using substitution of `for` variable:

```
    %%~i   - expands %%i removing any surrounding quotes (")
    %%~fi  - expands %%i to a fully qualified path name only
    %%~ni  - expands %%i to a file name only
    %%~xi  - expands %%i to a file extension only

    %%~nxi => expands %%~i to a file name and extension
```

- Using `find/i` and `"%%~i"` and `"%%~fi"`

```all-bat
  pushd "%~dp0PDF" 
  for %%i in (*.pdf)do type "log.txt" | find/i "%%~i">nul && del/q "%%~fi" || echo/"%%~i">>log.txt
```

- Using `find/i` and `"%%~nxi"`

```all-bat
  pushd "%~dp0PDF" 
  for %%i in (*.pdf)do type "log.txt" | find/i "%%~nxi">nul && del/q "%%~i" || echo/"%%~nxi">>log.txt
```

- Without using `pushd` and using `"%%~nxi"` and `%%~fi`

```all-bat
   for %%i in ("%~dp0pdf\*.pdf")do type "%~dp0PDF\log.txt" | find /i "%%~nxi">nul && del/q ""%~dp0pdf\%%~fi" || echo\"%%~nxi">>"%~dp0PDF\log.txt"
```

- Without using `pushd` and using `findstr /ilc:` and "%%~nxi"

```all-bat
  for %%i in ("%~dp0pdf\*.pdf"
  )do type "%~dp0PDF\log.txt" | findstr /ilc:"%%~nxi" >nul && (
  del/q "%~dp0pdf\%%~nxi") || echo\"%%~nxi">>"%~dp0PDF\log.txt"
```

---

You can use redirection in your loop with `find` command and operators `&&` and `||`:

1. List the files with this simple method:

```all-bat
   for %%i in (*.pdf)do...
```

2. Check that the file `%%i` is in your `log.txt` using the `type` command redirecting the output to the `find /i "%%~i"` command:

```all-bat
   type "log.txt"| find /i "%%~i"...
```

3. Use operator (conditional execution) `&&` and `||`, for if match/-not-match do `del file.pdf` or `echo file.pdf`:

```all-bat
   && del/Q "%%F" || echo/"%%~i">>log.txt
```

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[For](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)**

  [√] **[For /F](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)**

  [√] **[Find](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html)**

  [√] **[Findstr](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)**

  [√] **[Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)**

  [√] **[Conditional Execution || && ...](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)**